# How to pass an image source in jade from a variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

This is my code from my index.js file (using express for routing)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   var db = req.db;
   var collection = db.get('usercollection');
   var source = req.app.get('imgSource');
   console.log("IMG SOURCE: " + source);
   collection.find({},{},function(e,docs,source){
     res.render('index',{
      "userlist" : docs,
      "imgURL" : source,
      "title": "Insta-Famous"
     });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my code from my index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
 h1= title
 p Welcome to #{title}
 ul
  each user, i in userlist
    li
        p #{user.instaid}
        p #{user.price}
    li
        img(src = "#{imgURL}")
```

source is a variable that is defined in app.js and then used in my index.js file. I know this variable has a value because it prints to console.log when I start my application. However the image does not load and instead displays a 404 question mark.

If I copy and paste the image source (which is: http://naccrra.org/sites/default/files/default_site_pages/2013/instagram-icon.png) then the image loads fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you look at your network tab in your browser, does the request for the image fire off as expected?  And the address is correct?

Comment: Why are you passing `source` to `collection.find`'s callback function? I don' think you're supposed to. It'll still be available to `res.render` if you didn't. In fact I think it's being set it to `undefined` that way which is most likely your issue.

Comment: Thank you laggingreflex, that was exactly the problem. I'm new to javascript so I was unaware of that but it 100% makes sense. You should make your comment a response so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were accepting an argument with the same name that the varible from outer scope has and which you intended to use - `source`

```
var source = req.app.get('imgSource');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs,source){
 ...
});
```

Any named argument to a function takes precedence over the same name variable of the outer scope. For example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
function fn(a){
    a //=> 'precedence'
    b //=> 2
}
fn('precedence');
```

If no variable was passed when calling, but the definition still takes a named argument, that argument will automatically be `undefined`, which is what was happening in your case. `collection.find`'s callback is only ever called with two arguments - `e` and `docs`, any sunsequent arguments if named would have been set to `undefined`

You simply needed not take that extra named argument, which was unnecessary in the first place.

```
var source = req.app.get('imgSource');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
 ...
});
```